# Detect if mouse is dragged or clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using raycast on an object and the ray hits when mouse is clicked on the object. However, I do not want the ray to fire if the mouse is being dragged (mouse button being pressed for more than 2 seconds). How do I achieve this?

```
    void Update () {
        RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit ();
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0) || Input.touchCount == 1) {
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hitInfo, 10)) {
                Debug.Log(hitInfo.collider.gameObject.name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Raycast` has to be done only when the pressed duration is less than 2 seconds, we implement a timer to keep track of the time passed since the key was pressed and reset it to `0` as soon as the pressed button is released. When the mouse button is pressed and the time passed is less than 2 seconds, do raycast.

```
private float timer = 0f;

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer <= 2f) {
            // do raycast
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        timer = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it still does not solve the drag/click issue.

Comment: I've edited my answer, correct me if I didn't understand the question right